# Haskell Stack Local Server

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, stackage

I am behind a firewall with strict rules about downloading software from the internet, so I would like to know if it is possible to download an entire stackage LTS snapshot in one go and serve it on a local server, to which we could then point the stack tool.

By "snapshot" I would be referring to the source code for all packages because ideally we'd need to draw from that local server to build on multiple (stack-supported) platforms (Linux, Windows).

For example, it would be nice to be able to go to a new machine within the firewall, then run "stack new", then edit the yaml file to point it to a local stackage server with given resolver number, then it would just behave normally from then on, except always downloading packages from the local server.

What about compilers?  I know that stack also downloads the compilers, so I guess those would have to be included in the downloaded snapshot-package for various platforms right?

Thank you

Comment: I think this can be done with a bit of work. Here are a few relevant links: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#urls, https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#setup-info. Packages are usually downloaded from https://s3.amazonaws.com/hackage.fpcomplete.com, but I think it would only take a small patch to make that configurable.

Comment: To increase your reach you could also post to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/haskell-stack and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/stackage.

Comment: @sjakobi Thanks -- I'll post to those groups as well.